# Ubuntu Restore window size after Unmaximize

Tags: 16.04, window, maximized

My problem is when I maximize the terminal for example then I double click on the panel to unmaximize the window (terminal) the window will unmaximize but the size still almost the same (full screen) not the size like before the maximize.

How I can restore the windows size e.g( terminal) after unmaximize?

Comment: @JacobVlijm It is  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1521302

Comment: @JacobVlijm well can't you make a script for the guy while they're waiting for bug to be fixed ? Id say you just need to poll wmctrl every 2 seconds or so and check if net wm state is not maximized. If it is, stop polling and wait for state to revert, and use xdotool to resize back

Comment: @Hizqeel thanks for the info we will wait for the fix

Comment: @Jacobvlijm  that will be ok too. I just thought automating the behavior is more user friendly way

Comment: @JacobVlijm i actually me English is week and i don't fully understand it :(. , Please explain more

Comment: @JacobVlijm Inded very nice workaround its worked. You may add it as an answer, Thanks.

Comment: @RepeatUntil if You find that as a Useful answer You have to mark that as an Accepted

Comment: @JacobVlijm Both works, I think is your workaround and the accepted answer is the same maximize `Ctrl+Super+↑`  unmaximize `Ctrl+Super+↓` , is this what you Meant in the workaround?

Comment: @JacobVlijm i updated the answer but still under review you have to check it.

Comment: We should really stop meeting like this :) (and remove the comments), but it simply doesn't work here. Nice that it works on your system, not on mine, and yes, I read the edit well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the keyboard shortcut to maximize the window via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd> Then to bring the window to the same size use the unmaximize shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>↓</kbd>

> Note: If you maximized the window via double-click and want to unmaximize(while double-clicking) it will not be the same as it was before.

Comment: Nope, not in 16.04, else double click would work as well.

Comment: «not in 16.04» Why not? It does what is written in the post.

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto not on my system (16.04) it does exactly the same as double click, *not* resize to the original size. It seems to work however for OP.

Comment: @JacobVlijm It actually did worked on my system(16.04) that's why I was pretty Confident about my answer

Comment: @JacobVlijm is your install an upgrade from a previous version or a fresh install?

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto nope, brand new, fresh install.

Comment: not in kUuntu 20.4 dont found a unmaximize shortcut

Answer (score 0):

Install **CompizConfig Settings Manager** from ubuntu software center and go into CompizConfig Settings Manager--> Window Management and see if **all boxes** are ticked.

this tool can help to increase the usability of x window system.